# Information not remembered when dealing with multiple lines in a file

Tags: c

So let's say that a file has multiply lines each containing one word. I want to store the characters of every word in every line in a array. The code below clearly doesn't work because the -i is zeroed in every loop and the program starts storing characters in the 1st position of the array again. The code is:

```
while(1)
{
    if(fgets(str, 50, fp) == NULL)
        break;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
        p[i] = str[i];
}
```

Comment: Note that the array `p` is not null-terminated after the inner loop.  If `p` is a character type, you could use `strcpy()` instead of your inner loop.  You could use `while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL) { …copy data… }`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your file reading loop like this;

```
 while (fgets(str, sizeof(yourString), fp) != NULL)
  {
    yourString[strlen(yourString) - 1] = '\0'; // delete the new line
    printf("%s\n", yourString);
  }
```

So simply in the above code, your `while` loop will be working until there is no another line to read in the file. In each turn of `while` loop, it will take one line from your file, and add it to your `yourString` char array. Notice that, `fgets()` will be taking newline characters too (`\n`) for every line in the file, so that we need to remove this characters from the array before we add another line in it.

Before the `while` loop, You need to declare a `char` array to store each line in it such as;

```
char yourString[stringSize];
```

You need to determine a `stringSize` for your array to make it has enough storage for your file.

Answer (score 1):

you have separate counter variable for p and keep incrementing it to avoid 
overwritting, like below.

```
int write_position = 0;

while(1)
{
if(fgets(str, 50, fp) == NULL)
    break;
for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    p[write_position++] = str[i]; // you will not lose previous ones here 
}
```

at the end lenght of the array p is equal to write_position

Comment: You could also use `for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)` which saves scanning the string twice (once in `strlen()`, once in the copy loop.  And testing `strlen()` on each iteration could well lead to quadratic behaviour if the optimizer isn't able to deduce that the call can be made just once.

Comment: this will NOT work.  In the end, all the entries in the array will point to `str`

Comment: @user3629249 No, copying is happening from str to p charcter by charcter, how it point to str ? str is buffer which holds whatever read from fgets(),  after reading copying to p,  so p will *never* point to str ,

Comment: this results in all the input data being contained serialized in the one (huge) array 'P'  The way I read the question, the OP wants to have an array of char strings, with each input word in a separate entity in the array

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code snippet

1. performs the desired functionality
2. assumes that the array 'p[]' is an array of char pointers to pointers and contains (at least) enough entries to hold all the lines in the input file
3. no line in the input file is longer than 48 characters + newline

And now the proposed code:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 50

char **p;
p = calloc( NUM_LINES_IN_FILE, sizeof( char * ) );
if( !p )
{
    perror( "calloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, calloc successful
FILE *fp;
if( !(fp = fopen ( "inputFileName", "r" )) )
{
    perror( "fopen failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful

char str[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
for( int i=0; fgets(str, sizeof( str ), fp); i++ )
{
    // remove trailing newline char
    str[ strcspn( str, '\n' ) ]  = '\0';
    p[i] = strdup( str );
}
fclose( fp );
```